# How to configure environment URL via TestNG parameterization?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, rest-assured

I have created a framework for RestAssured API automation. As in most cases, there are 2 servers: Staging & Production. I want to parameterize the same via TestNG XML file and specify which environment to use.

Once specificed, i want to have a method that sets the BaseURL for all subsequent request as common, since i don't want to write `RestAssured.baseURI="http://stagingURL.com/"` in each of the test case i run.
This is what i am setting in TestNG.XML file
`<parameter name="env" value="Staging"/>`

How to go about writing a method that takes the value as `Staging/production` and adjusts the Base URL accordingly.  I tried writing this class, but it does not work

```
public class Environment {
    public static String env;
    public static String baseURL;

    @Test
    @Parameters({"env"})
    public static String getEnvironmentURL(){
        if(env=="Production"){
            baseURL="http://prodURL.com/";
        }
        else if(env=="Staging"){
            baseURL="http://stagingURL.com/";
        }
        return RestAssured.baseURI=baseURL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have used is correct, though as you are matching the String values in the parameters, you need to use either `contains` or `equals` method instead of `==` as `==` matches the references and `contains` /`equals` matches the values.

So, you need to make the following changes in your code:

```
@Test
@Parameters({"env"})
public static String getEnvironmentURL(){
    if(env.equals("Production")){
        baseURL="http://prodURL.com/";
    }
    else if(env.equals("Staging")){
        baseURL="http://stagingURL.com/";
    }
    return RestAssured.baseURI=baseURL;
}
```